# How to create a Django queryset based on items from another

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using Django 2.2.28 and Python 3.7.7 in a legacy application. I have a display page that displays People based on a `class PeopleQuerySet(models.QuerySet)` that's filtered and paginated. This works, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do something like this:

```
new_people_queryset = PeopleQuerySet()
for person in existing_queryset.iterator():
    if some_condition:
        new_people_queryset.add(person)
```

Is there a way to do what I'm implying above; create an empty PeopleQuerySet() object and then insert people into it from a queryset that's the result of filtering? The `some_condition` thing is some arbitrary Python logic I'm using for illustration purposes here.

Any ideas, pointers, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying a filter to the existing queryset? Can you add an example of the condition and your model?

Comment: I think you can solve that with Django subquery expressions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: Thanks, both of these suggestions are what I was looking for. I created an additional filter based on a list of id values and then filtered on the query id being IN that list. Thanks!